# Filtering a dataset after grepl in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
USERNAME API_TRACK_EVENT         TIME
userA    Viewed pic              1454941960
userA    Order/payment           1454941972
userA    Order/Changed Address   1454941976
userB    Viewed pic              1454941983
userB    Order/guestlogin        1454941986
userB    Order/Changed Address   1454941992
```

I want to take only the earlier "Order", which means "Order/payment" for userA and "Order/guestlogin" for userB.

Having said that, all the other non-order events should remain the same.

So, the output dataset would be:

```
USERNAME API_TRACK_EVENT         TIME
userA    Viewed pic              1454941960
userA    Order/payment           1454941972
userB    Viewed pic              1454941983
userB    Order/guestlogin        1454941986
```

So, how should I do this?  [Open to use dplyr too.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option with base R:

0) order the data according to USERNAME and TIME:

```
df <- df[order(df$USERNAME, df$TIME),]
```

a) Check whether rows contain order-information:

```
idx <- grepl("Order", df$API_TRACK_EVENT, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

b) Subset by group of USERNAME

```
subset(df, ave(idx, USERNAME, FUN = cumsum) <= 1L | !idx)

#  USERNAME  API_TRACK_EVENT       TIME
#1    userA       Viewed_pic 1454941960
#2    userA    Order/payment 1454941972
#4    userB       Viewed_pic 1454941983
#5    userB Order/guestlogin 1454941986
```

This subsets only the first order-row and any other rows (without order info).

Comment: Sorry that I missed the detail that the rows need to be order acc. to `time` and the earliest one should exist in the resulting dataset.  Thanks to your comment on the other answer, I've got reminded about the mistake :)

Comment: @Dawny33, I added a step to order the data

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `slice/which.max/grep` to filter out the rows in `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'USERNAME', we get a logical index with `grepl`, wrap it with `which.max` to get the numeric index of the first TRUE value, use `seq` to obtain the sequence from `1:index` and `slice` it to subset the rows.  This approach assumes that the "Order" elements occur at the end for each "USERNAME" as showed in the example.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    arrange(USERNAME, TIME) %>%
    group_by(USERNAME) %>%
    slice(seq(which.max(grepl("Order", API_TRACK_EVENT))))
#  USERNAME  API_TRACK_EVENT       TIME
#     <chr>            <chr>      <int>
#1    userA       Viewed pic 1454941960
#2    userA    Order/payment 1454941972
#3    userB       Viewed pic 1454941983
#4    userB Order/guestlogin 1454941986
```

However, if the "Order" elements are not ordered, we can use `duplicated` with `grepl` to keep the rows that have any element that do not have 'Order' or only the first 'Order' element.

```
df1 %>%
    arrange(USERNAME, TIME) %>%
    group_by(USERNAME) %>%
    filter( {idx =  grepl("^Order", API_TRACK_EVENT);
            !duplicated(idx)|!idx})

#  USERNAME  API_TRACK_EVENT       TIME
#     <chr>            <chr>      <int>
#1    userA       Viewed pic 1454941960
#2    userA    Order/payment 1454941972
#3    userB       Viewed pic 1454941983
#4    userB Order/guestlogin 1454941986
```

NOTE: Edited with contributions from @docendodiscimus

---

Or using the first methodology with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[order(USERNAME, TIME), .I[seq(which.max(grepl("Order", 
                       API_TRACK_EVENT)))], USERNAME]$V1]
```

Comment: Possible to explain the last line? `slice(seq(which.max(grep("Order", API_TRACK_EVENT))))` <-- This

Comment: @akrun (+1)Thanks for the answer.  What change can be done if it needs to be ordered according to time, and want to take the `most early` one?  Sorry for missing the detail in the qn :)

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Thanks for the comment.  I forgot about the `{}`