# Ordering and filtering(delete) the rows after a grepl in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
USERNAME API_TRACK_EVENT         TIME
userA    Viewed pic              1454941960
userA    Order/payment           1454941972
userA    Edit pic                1454941973
userA    Order/Changed Address   1454941976
userB    Viewed pic              1454941983
userB    Order/guestlogin        1454941986
userB    Order/Changed Address   1454941992
```

I want to do the following on the dataset:

- Order the dataset w.r.t `TIME`
- Delete all the `APITRACK_EVENT`s after the first occurrence of an "Order" event  (Target is to get all the api tracking events of the user, before a first order is placed).

So, how should I go ahead with this? [Open to using dplyr too.]

---

[A (somewhat)related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37920370/4993513)

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: @Heroka In the linked post, you can notice that I tried to get the df ordered w.r.t `TIME` and then, filtered out the non-first "order" occurences. 

However, wasn't been able to do the `Delete all the APITRACK_EVENTs after the first occurrence of an "Order" event` part.

Comment: @akrun No. I need to **remove** all the `API_TRACKING` events after the first occurrence of an "order" event, not just deleting the non-first "order" occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we `arrange` by 'USERNAME', 'TIME' and grouped by 'USERNAME', we the index of the first occurrence of 'Order' with `grepl` and `which.max`.  Add 1 to it and get the sequence (`:`) from it to the nrow (`n()`).  As we need to remove these rows from the dataset, we can use `setdiff` to find the row index that are not in the created index and `slice` it.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  arrange(USERNAME, TIME) %>%
  group_by(USERNAME) %>%
  slice(setdiff(row_number(), (which.max(grepl("Order", 
                                API_TRACK_EVENT))+1): n()))    
#   USERNAME  API_TRACK_EVENT       TIME    
#      <chr>            <chr>      <int>
#1    userA       Viewed pic 1454941960
#2    userA    Order/payment 1454941972
#3    userB       Viewed pic 1454941983
#4    userB Order/guestlogin 1454941986
```

---

Another option is with `filter`

```
df1 %>%
   arrange(USERNAME, TIME) %>% 
   group_by(USERNAME) %>% 
   filter(!lag(cumsum(grepl("Order", API_TRACK_EVENT)), default = 0))
#   USERNAME  API_TRACK_EVENT       TIME
#     <chr>            <chr>      <int>
#1    userA       Viewed pic 1454941960
#2    userA    Order/payment 1454941972
#3    userB       Viewed pic 1454941983
#4    userB Order/guestlogin 1454941986
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you explain the last line, please (The `slice ..` one) :)

Comment: @Dawny33 Added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Made my day :)